# How to install additional packages in WinPython?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been using WinPython 2.2.5 with Python 2.7 and it works nice. The problem that I have is when I want to install additional libraries to use from the https://pypi.python.org repository.

For example I tried to install pdfminer which is in following link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer/

I have read that I can use pip install which is in the following path on my computer:

```
C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6\Scripts
```

On that directory I have saved the tar.gz file of pdfminer and from the windows command prompt on the aforementioned path I have typed:

```
pip install pdfminer(version number).tar.gz
```

It seems that it works fine, because there are no error messages, but when I open the winpython and in the command shell I put:

```
pdf2txt
```

to see if it works I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pdf2txt' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `pdf2txt.py` is a command line tool, not something you import.

Comment: @n1c9: The OP isn't trying to `import` it.

Comment: @martineau well regardless, you wouldn't call it from the command shell, right?

Comment: @n1c9: The `pdf2txt.py` file is a command-line tool designed to be run from the prompt of a Windows console shell.

Comment: but his post says "I opened up WinPython and in the command shell I put..".  I've never used WinPython - is the WinPython command shell the same as the Windows command shell?

Comment: @n1c9: I'm not familiar with WinPython either and was about to ask the OP what kind of "command shell" they're using, Windows' or Python's. For the former the path to the folder the `pdf2txt.py` is in would have to be appended to the shell's `PATH` environment variable (or the complete path to it would have to be specified in the shell: i.e. `C:\path\to\pdfminer\tools\pdf2txt.py`).

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation,](http://euske.github.io/pdfminer/index.html#intro) "PDFMiner comes with two handy tools: pdf2txt.py and dumppdf.py."  So, instead of trying to run `pdf2txt.py` by importing it, you need to run it as it shows in the example in the documentation, like this:

```
$ pdf2txt.py -o output.html samples/naacl06-shinyama.pdf
```

where `output.html` is the file that is created from the mined text, and `samples/naac106-shinyama.pdf` is the PDF you want to mine.